# Button for swipe events without click default animation

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic, angular & HTML (noob alert). I'm trying to create a swipe surface for swipe events and using a button tag. My problem is that I don't need the default behavior of clicking a button and more specifically the default animation that comes with it. It should be swipe only for mobile.

Is there a way of doing that? I suspect that this is very basic and my approach is probably wrong.

My Swipe key Directive:

```
app.directive('swipeKey', ['DimensionCalculator', function(DimensionCalculator) {  return {
restrict: 'E',
replace: true,
template: '<button><img src="../img/1465502670_Spread.png"></img></button>',
link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
  console.log("swipeKey Directive: getSwipeButtonHeight=" +  DimensionCalculator.getSwipeButtonHeight());

  elem.css('height',  DimensionCalculator.getSwipeButtonHeight() + 'px');
  elem.css('width', DimensionCalculator.getSwipeButtonWidth() + 'px');
  elem.css('position', 'fixed');
  elem.css('background', 'url(../img/brushed1.jpg)');
  elem.css('z-index', '1');
```

my HTML:

```
<swipe-key on-swipe-up="Game.handleSwipeUp()" on-swipe-down="Game.handleSwipeDown()" on-tap="Game.handleSwipeUp()"></swipe-key>
```

The DimensionCalculator is a service for dimensions.

Everything works fine except that I don't need the default 'click' animation that the button has.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What problems have you encountered? please edit the question to post your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

As i feared this was something very basic. In order to achieve the requested behavior I shouldn't be using a button, a div will do.